# maparg returns empty string, but the mapping is effective

Tags: key-bindings

I have a mapping set by a plugin that I want to unmap, which is the sequence "cop". The mapping is defined in unimpaired plugin: `nnoremap cop <Nop>`.

If I do

```
:map cop
n  cop         * <Nop>
```

So the mapping is there.

But I fail to detect it in my script (I don't want `nunmap` , because maparg("cop", "n") returns an empty string:

```
:echo empty(maparg("cop", "n"))
1
```

However, `maparg("cop", "n", 0, 1)` returns:

```
{'silent': 0, 'noremap': 1, 'lhs': 'cop', 'mode': 'n', 'nowait': 0, 'expr': 0, 'sid': 34, 'rhs': '<Nop>', 'buffer': 0}
```

Why does the first maparg returns an empty string, and how to detect if the mapping is present?

(Vim 8.0.1453)

Comment: I could not reproduce this in Vim 8.1.1004. Might be fixed in between. Maybe [this issue](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/2940) fixed by [this commit](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/f88a5bc10232cc3fac92dba4e8455f4c14311f8e).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Ralf comment, upgrading to Vim 8.1 solved the issue